# How to add top x-axis in xmgrace?

Tags: plot, axis-labels, xmgrace

I have plotted a graph with xmgrace, the x-values are in linear scale of nm (for wavelength). I want to add a top reciprocal x-axis in eV units.

The formula to transform nm to eV is:

[image: eV=\frac{1240}{nm}]

I could not find a way to add another x-axis without adding a new data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible without any particular hack which, since we are dealing with xmgrace, is quite amazing :-)
Here is how you do it:

- Open the axis properties
- Select the "Alt X axis" option in the "edit" drop-down menu
- Go to the "Tick labels" tab
- Select "Opposite" as the Placement side
- Put "1240 / $t" in the "Axis transform" textbox at the bottom
- Click "Apply"